# Nested CiviEvents

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

Hi to all (and thank you in advance).

I am looking for a way to nest CiviEvents. We run small conferences that sometimes have sessions during the day. We need to use the same functionality (and fields) that we have for an event, for its session (with the addition of time e.g. 09:30 - 11:30 / which I can do).

Example:

Conference about the healing powers of coffee

1. Session 01 (09:30 - 11:30) - To drink or not to drink
2. Session 02 (11:30 - 13:30) - The importance of Biscotti

Is there an add-in, extension, module etc that does this? (or any other way that does not require to re-invent the wheel)

Best A.

Comment: Forgot to mentions CiviCRM 5.13.4 / Drupal 7

Answer (score 4):

Karin's approach is good; the Civi-native way (in case you're not on Drupal) is to use Price Sets for sessions.  This is covered in the [Complex Event Fees](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/complex-event-fees/) section of the CiviEvent documentation.  They're very configurable, and allow you to set per-session limits, additional costs for some (or all) sessions, and more.

If you go this route, install the Extended Reports extension because its Event/Participant with Line Item reports specifically address some of the shortcomings of the built-in reporting for this use case.

Comment: Ah I figured they were using Drupal because of the civicrm-entity tag

Answer (score 3):

We use Webform CiviCRM modules for this: 
Sessions are custom CiviCRM fields on the Partipant entity and Webform Select Limit module lets you put limits on how many participants can select a certain Session.

Comment: Thx KarinG. I've seen this. I was hoping for some simpler way that allowed just a field to define the "parent". I'm looking at reusing the lookup field provided in the "Conference Slots" tab and move it to the "Info and Settings" tab as standard.

Comment: This is quite simple though in terms of code/sustainability/usability; and admin has full control over the custom fields (when people change their mind); we use this config for clients who organize major conferences;